# MATLAB to convert xy plot to xyz array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, geometry

I have a series of curves plotted in x vs. y format in MATLAB. I want to describe the shape they create at their intersection in an xyz format (a 2D array).

There is no simple function in MATLAB to do the conversion, so I am wondering if anyone has a quick workaround.

Here is a simple example. I create my default grid:

```
nx = 100;   % Number of grid points
X = 1;      % Default total grid size (cm)
dx = X/nx;  % Default grid step size (cm)
```

I create a set of parabolas and lines, using my grid and a scaled grid:

```
x1 = (-nx/2:1:nx/2-1)*dx;   % grid 1 (cm)
x2 = (-nx/2:1:nx/2-1)*dx*2; % grid 2 (cm)
y1 = x1.^2;                 % parabola 1 
y2 = -x2.^2 + 2;            % parabola 2 
y3 = -1.5*x2-.5;            % line 1
y4 = 1.5*x2-.5;             % line 2
```

Finally, I can plot the shape I want to describe:

```
figure(1)
plot(x1,y1)
hold on;
plot(x2,y2)
hold on;
plot(x2,y3)
hold on
plot(x2,y4)
xlabel('x coordinate (cm)')
ylabel('y coordinate (cm)')
```

Note that both my x and y coordinates are in units of cm. I wish to create a 2D matrix where 1's appear inside the "eye" region, and 0's appear outside:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJP8.jpg

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define a meshgrid and evaluate a logical expression corresponding to each of the four functions.
Then I would just calculate the intersection of them.

I don't think it would work on different `x1` and `x2` grids, because you need to evaluate the functions on the same `x` values.

Something like this:

```
nx = 100;   % Number of grid points
X = 1;      % Default total grid size (cm)
dx = X/nx;  % Default grid step size (cm)

xq = (-nx/2:1:nx/2-1)*dx*2;   % grid x (cm)
yq = (-nx/2:1:nx/2-1)*dx*4;   % grid y (cm)


[XX, YY] = meshgrid(xq, yq);

ZZ_1 = (YY > XX.^2); % upper range of function 1
ZZ_2 = (YY < -XX.^2 + 2); % bottom range of function 2
ZZ_3 = (YY > -1.5*XX - 0.5); % upper range of function 3
ZZ_4 = (YY > 1.5*XX - 0.5); % upper range of function 4

ZZ = int8(ZZ_1 & ZZ_2 & ZZ_3 & ZZ_4); % the intersection of all functions

figure;
surf(XX, YY, ZZ);
```

[image: Intersection of the four logical arrays]